# Dapper One to Many Mapping Logic

Tags: dapper

The dapper tutorial gives this example to help a user with Multi Mapping (One to Many)
While this works I am curious why they have you store the orders in the dictionary but then in the end they use a linq.Distinct() and return from the list. It seems like it would be cleaner to just return the ordersDictionary.Values as the dictionary logic ensures no duplicates.

```
//Tutorial
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(FiddleHelper.GetConnectionStringSqlServerW3Schools()))
{            
    Dictionary<int,Order> orderDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Order>();
    List<Order> list = connection.Query<Order, OrderDetail, Order>(sql, (order, orderDetail) =>
    {
        if (!orderDictionary.TryGetValue(order.OrderID, out Order orderEntry))
        {
            orderEntry = order;
            orderEntry.OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
            orderDictionary.Add(orderEntry.OrderID, orderEntry);
        }
        orderEntry.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);
        return orderEntry;
    }, splitOn: "OrderID")
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
    return list;
}

//my suggestion
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(FiddleHelper.GetConnectionStringSqlServerW3Schools()))
{            
    Dictionary<int,Order> orderDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Order>();
    //change 1 no need to store into list here
    connection.Query<Order, OrderDetail, Order>(sql, (order, orderDetail) =>
    {
        if (!orderDictionary.TryGetValue(order.OrderID, out Order orderEntry))
        {
            orderEntry = order;
            orderEntry.OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
            orderDictionary.Add(orderEntry.OrderID, orderEntry);
        }
        orderEntry.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);
        return orderEntry;
    }, splitOn: "OrderID"); //change 2 remove .Distinct().ToList()
    return orderDictionary.Values.ToList(); //change 3 return dictionaryValues
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of this tutorial: https://dapper-tutorial.net/query#example-query-multi-mapping-one-to-many

> why they have you store the orders in the dictionary

A row is returned for every `OrderDetail`. So you want to make sure to add the `OrderDetail` to the existing `Order` and not create a new one for every `OrderDetail`. The dictionary is used for performance to check if the `Order` has been already created or not.

> it would be cleaner to just return the ordersDictionary.Values

How will your query return dictionary values?

Of course, if you are in a method such as yours, you can do

```
var list = orderDictionary.Values;
return list;
```

But how to make this `Connection.Query` return dictionary values? An order is returned for every row/`OrderDetail`, so the order will be returned multiple times.

Outside the `Query`, your dictionary solution works great and is even a better solution for performance, but if you want to make your `Query` return the distinct list of orders without using `Distinct` or some similar method, it's impossible.

**EDIT: Answer comment**

> my suggestion return orderDictionary.Values.ToList(); //change 3 return dictionaryValues

Thank you for your great feedback, it's always appreciated ;)

It would be weird in a tutorial to use what the query returns when there is no relationship but use the dictionary for `one to many` relationships

```
// no relationship
var orders = conn.Query<Order>("", ...).Distinct();

// one to many relationship
conn.Query<Order, OrderDetail>("", ...);
var orders = orderDictionary.Values.ToList();
```

Your solution is better for performance the way you use it, there is no doubt about this. But this is how people usually use the `Query` method:

```
var orders = conn.Query("", ...).Distinct();

var activeOrders = orders.Where(x => x.IsActive).ToList();
var inactiveOrders = orders.Where(x => !x.IsActive).ToList();
```

They use what the `Query` method returns.

But again, there is nothing wrong with the way you do it, this is even better if you can do it.

Comment: cool. First of all thanks so much for the tutorial it has been super helpful as i migrate from EF to Dapper. I added a second example to my question demonstrating my tweaks. the words of my question didnt clearly illustrate my point.